# getting error “Table doesn't exist” in magento innodb database when browsing in phpmyadmin or sqlYog

Tags: error, mysql, database

I have moved magento database (copy and paste xampp/mysql directory) from another system to my laptop(windows7,xampp), and configure mysql service path(xampp control panel showing run mysql fine). But now I am not able to access magento database, only 19 tables are listed in phpmyadmin.

all tables are listed in sqlyog, but when i browse them getting error message "table not exist".

I try to recover and follow this article steps, but when I am run this command 
`mysqld –innodb_log_file_size=5242880 –innodb_force_recovery=6` on command window, getting an error " Can't create test file \usr\local\mysql\data.lower-test". Can you please suggest me why am i getting this error and how can I resolve it?

If above error we can ignore I mean this error not responsible for get back database then please suggest me how can I get back my database?

PS: I also copied "ibdata1", "ib_logfile0" and "ib_logfile1" on mysql directory. Now I can't access database from old system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have backups (mysql dumps) from the old system prior to this fiasco, you might want to start from scratch with them. I take it you cannot access the database on the old system because you either destructively moved the database files to the new system or for some reason copied the files you copied to the new system back to the old system. Got a system backup?

Answer (score 5):

FTPing or copying and pasting innodb tables from one filesystem to another isn't going to work. Try this to restore innodb tables:

[http://egil.biz/how-to-recover-mysql-data-from-innodb/][1]

Better yet, do nightly dumps of your magento database:

```
mysqldump -u david -h localhost -pmypassword mymagentodatabase > mymagentodatabase.sql | gzip mymagentodatabase.sql
```

To restore, open up mysql on the command line:

```
use mymagentodatabase
source /home/david/mymagentodatabase.sql
```

Restoring from the mysql command line is way faster than using a client like navicat or phpmyadmin.

In my work environment, I also have a clone of the production code base on my development machine, such as: http://dev.magentowebsite.com. When I have to, I restore the last dump to my local mysql, then go into core_config_data and change the secure and nonsecure urls to http://dev.magentowebsite.com. Then I have the live site on my local machine and can test things without breaking the live site.

Answer (score 0):

The same question was (kind of) answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18106909/2047249). I had this issue before and I wasn't able to solve it (but I've learned my lesson). I found [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/16911) on dba.stackexchange.com. Follow the links in the answer, maybe it helps.

---

<sub>Maybe this question is more suited for dba.stackexchange.com since it's not a Magento question. This "issue" reproduces for any innodb database</sub>